# Facebook Graph API get friends of friends

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, request

I'm using the Facebook's Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), and query the "friends" field on my friends. But it always give me:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported operation", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Is this error supposed to happen? If it is, then is there any way to crawl Facebook friends' friends using other methods?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: No you can't. It is not possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requesting the friends of friends was never possible via the Graph API. Even more, starting with v2.0 you'll only see friends who are also using the same app if you request `/{user_id}/friends`

Comment: Too true... The poor fairies.